# Samson GTrack USB mic on Windows 7

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

Has anyone used Samson GTrack on Windows 7? I read an Amazon review that almost changed my mind about buying the mic when I was about to hit the 'Add to Cart' button.

I'd like to use the microphone for podcasting and for making screencasts.

**Update**

Here are some of the reviews I came across about it not working properly with Windows 7 (Home (Premium & Basic) and Starter versions, and even some other versions of Windows like XP SP2 and Vista).

They say that the mic produces a hiss sound when used with these operating systems.

http://www.amazon.com/review/RBU403WVQ06M1/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0015MJE22&linkCode=&nodeID=&tag=

http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/80270-samson-g-track.html

http://forum.cakewalk.com/tm.aspx?m=1530713

Comment: "Has anyone used one" is too open-ended to be useful on this site. Do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that. Thanks. I've updated my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bug in Windows Vista/7 [where it defaults to +30 dB of digital gain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/default-audio-volume-settings) instead of 0 dB. Turn down the volume slider to 0 dB and you're fine. [Windows 7: Samson G-Track](http://sevenforums.com/sound-audio/80270-samson-g-track.html)

Alternatively, use an [ASIO solution](http://5ise.quanxinquanyi.de/2010/12/03/samson-g-track-static-noise-and-windows-7/) like [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.com/), which will bypass the Windows volume control completely.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see a Gain control in my Sound control panel applet against the properties of the microphone. Where should I be looking?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 in Sound applet, go to Recording tab, then "USB Audio CODEC", Properties button, then Levels tab.  Right-click the number and select "decibels" if it's not already selected, then turn the level down to 0 dB (or "-0.4 dB", close enough)

Comment: Ah, "the right-click the number" part did it for me. I always had went about right till the properties tab. I never thought to right-click it. Thank you. :-)

But I observe that lowering the decibel value is not very different from lowering the percentage. Both of them pare down the amplitude of the signal. And then I get a really low signal, which I have to amplify. But the hiss is completely gone, even in the amplified signal. So, thank you very much. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Yes, the decibel value and percentage control the same thing, but the percentage is meaningless, and you specifically want it to be "0 dB" which means "do nothing".  And yes, to amplify, use the knob on the front of the mic, not the slider in Windows.